# Data Grid won't change after deleting source file

Tags: c#, winforms

I've a datagridview for display data from Text file. Then, i've a button that have function to delete content on Text file (return it to 0 bytes).

But why event execute (by clicking button), the datagrid doesn't refresh even using `.refresh()` function. Here's my code on button that deleting content of file text.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      File.WriteAllText("Transaction.txt", String.Empty);
      dataGridView1.Refresh();
}
```

PS : The datagridview would change (empty of course) only after re-launch Windows Form.

Comment: You have to re-bind, not refresh. The grid is not automatically in sync with the data unless you use a `BindingSource` and to do that with a text file would require wrapping the file access in some kind of enumerable.

Comment: Show how you loaded data to `DataGridView`? At least you need read file and load data again.

Comment: Hi @iMar I'm just wondering whether I have solved your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need `BindingList` class to bind data to your datagridview:

```
var _bindingList = new BindingList<string>();
```

And in your form constructor:

```
public MyForm
{
    InitializeComponent();
    myDataGridView.BindingSource = _bindingList;
}
```

Create a timer to monitor the change of file:

```
DateTime lastWriteTime = DateTime.Now
private void timer_tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FileInfo f = new FileInfo("C:\\myFile.txt");
    if ( lastWriteTime == f.LastWriteTime) return;
    lastWriteTime = f.LastWriteTime;
    UpdateBindingList();
}

private void UpdateBindingList()
{
    _bindingList.Clear();
    //then read the file and add items to _bindingList.
}
```